# Is it valid to prove this trigonometric identity by substituting this?

Tags: trigonometry

I wish to prove that $\sin{(\pi/2 -x)} = \cos{(x)}$. I have substituted $x+\pi/2$ for $x$ to eventually show equality between the right and left hand sides of this expression using the double angle formula.
My question is: does the fact that the expression I want to prove is true for $x+\pi/2$ as $x$ prove that it is true for all values of $x$? One the one hand, my thought is that the range of values which can be the output of the function $f(x)= x+\pi/2$ is exactly the same as the set of values which can be the output of the function $f(x)=x$; however, I feel that this equality was only able to be shown due to the $\pi/2$ being added to $x$, which isn't identical to $x$ itself.
for context, I am not very well versed in proofs yet, as I am a second year computer science student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your reasoning totally, but yes, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions with domain $\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x) = g(x)$ is equivalent to $f(x+\pi/2) = g(x+\pi/2)$.

Another way of proving that $\sin{(x-\pi/2)} = \cos{(x)}$ that is a bit more standard, by the way, is using the identity

\begin{equation*}
\sin{(\alpha\pm \beta)} = \sin{(\alpha)}\cos{(\beta)}\pm \cos{(\alpha)}\sin{(\beta)}
\end{equation*}

so that
\begin{equation*}
\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)} = \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\cos{(x)}-\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\sin{(x)} = 1\cdot\cos{(x)} - 0\cdot\sin{(x)} = \cos{(x)}.
\end{equation*}